# How can I use reflection to invoke DbModelBuilder.Entity<T>.Ignore(x => x.Property)?

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-5

I'm dynamically executing fluent mapping based on attributes on my poco classes and I have the .Property case working fine, but blows up trying to run the .Ignore() method:

```
private void AddEntities(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
    foreach (var entityType in EntityBaseTypes)
    {
        dynamic entityConfiguration = entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType).Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in entityType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanWrite))
        {

            foreach (var attribute in propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes())
            {
                LambdaExpression propertyLambda = PropertyGetLambda(entityType, propertyInfo.Name, typeof(string));
                string attributeName = attribute.GetType().Name;
                if (attributeName == "NotMappedAttribute")
                {
                    MethodInfo ignoreMethod = (MethodInfo)entityConfiguration.GetType().GetMethod("Ignore");                            
//BLOWS UP HERE: Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true
                    ignoreMethod.Invoke(entityConfiguration, new[] { propertyLambda });

                }
                else if (attributeName == "ColumnAttribute")
                {
                    dynamic column = attribute;
                    var propertyMethod = entityConfiguration.GetType().GetMethod("Property", new Type[] { propertyLambda.GetType() });
                    var entityProperty = (PrimitivePropertyConfiguration)propertyMethod.Invoke(entityConfiguration, new[] { propertyLambda });
//WORKS FINE:
                    entityProperty.HasColumnName(column.Name);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I think the type needed for the .Ignore() method parameters is different.  This is the method I'm attempting to call: [.Ignore()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671225%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

```
public void Ignore<TProperty>(
    Expression<Func<TStructuralType, TProperty>> propertyExpression
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to get the `MemberInfo` for the `Ignore` method using:

```
MethodInfo ignoreMethod = typeof(StructuralTypeConfiguration<>)
    .MakeGenericType(entityType)
    .GetMethod("Ignore")
    .MakeGenericMethod(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
```

`Ignore` is a method with a generic parameter corresponding to the property type of the `Expression`, so you need to supply the property type before you try to invoke it.

Comment: Worked perfectly called as: ignoreMethod.Invoke(entityConfiguration, new[] {  propertyLambda});        Thank you!